# Discord.py Помогите пж отправить сообщение участнику по ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Помогите пожалуйста я хочу отправить сообщение участнику по его ID

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx):
    user = 708709502341480510
    un = int(user)
    await un.send("Your message goes here")
```

но код не работает. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотреть в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm) и переписАть так:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx):
    user_id = 708709502341480510
    user = await client.get_user(user_id)
    
    await client.send_message(user, "Your message goes here")
```